# Python 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__' on list of lists

Tags: python-2.7

Usually this error means that there is an issue with parenthesis (e.g using brackets, missing, wrong spot, etc.) but  that doesn't appear to be the issue here.

```
#iterate through all the tiles on the map and set as a background color
for y in range(MAP_WIDTH):
    for x in range(MAP_HEIGHT):
        #checks if the tile is a wall
        wall = map[x][y].block_sight
        if wall:
            rlib.console_set_char_background(
            con, x, y, color_dark_wall, rlib.BKGND_SET)
        else:
            rlib.console_set_char_background(
            con, x, y, color_dark_ground, rlib.BKGND_SET)
```

The error occurs in the wall = map line. The map is a list of lists to simulate the functionality of an array within python. block_sight is either true or false and is setup here:

```
class Tile:
    #Tiles are components of the map
    def __init__(self, blocked, block_sight = None):
        #takes the information and stores it on the tile
        self.blocked = blocked

        #if not specified, block_sight if the same as blocked
        if block_sight is None: block_sight = blocked
        self.block_sight = block_sight
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is how the map is constructed:

```
#generates a list of lists with empty tiles as elements
def makemap():
    map = [[Tile(False) #Must call a conctructor, not a variable such as floor
        for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT)] #uses comprehension to generate lists
            for x in range(MAP_WIDTH)]

    #place two pillars to test the map
    map[30][22].blocked = True
    map[30][22].block_sight = True
    map[50][22].blocked = True
    map[50][22].block_sight = True
```

Comment: From the error it sure sounds like your list of lists is not actually what you expect. Perhaps the outer list contains a builtin function rather than an inner list. Can you show how you create `map`?

Comment: Can you get it to print out `map[x][y]` just before you call that line and see what you get?

Comment: Or maybe `map` is the builtin function that you use in functional-style programming, rather than your list of lists which has some other name?

Answer (score 0):

Within the function makemap(), I forgot to use map as a global variable, so anything that needed to use the map that this function build would not be able to access it. Adding "Global map" as the first line of the function resolved the error.